# php file() is returning boolean true instead of array of file contents

Tags: php, file

Bit of strange one here.

This works locally but when run on the staging server causes the code to fail because the `file()` function is returning a boolean true rather than array of records

Code excerpt:

```
if ( $input_list = file("{$path}/input_list.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) !== false) {
     foreach ($input_list as $row) {
          ... etc...
            }
}
```

The file exists (I access the dir/file via `DirectoryIterator`), it has content. The user executing the script has read & write permission to the folder and file.

if I `echo` a `gettype($input_list)` it returns: `bool(true)`

edit - I have also tried with out the different flags - FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES and FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES

Any ideas why it works locally (populates an array with records) but returns true on the server.

Server is php 5.3.21
TIA
PG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason it is doing this is because of the !== false.

You are first assigning the result of `file(..)` to `$input_file`, then checking if it is not equal to false. This will return true if the file exists.

So, remove the `!== false` so you have:

```
if($input_file = file("{$path}/test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)) {
    print_r($input_file);
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

Comment: Sweet thanks. That does the trick. I am however, confused, as my initial syntax works fine locally - the only difference being I'm on 5.4.10.

Answer (score 3):

You must use parentheses:

```
if(($input_list = file(…)) !== false) {
```

Otherwise, your condition would be interpreted as:

```
if($input_list = (file(…) !== FALSE)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that's not the issue. I amended my code to include the parentheses and got exactly the same result - boolean: true.